# How do I set the account ID or profile / role for CognitoIdentityProviderClient's addCustomAttributes?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-php-sdk

I'm interfacing with [CognitoIdentityProviderClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.CognitoIdentityProvider.CognitoIdentityProviderClient.html) as such:

```
class CognitoService
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct(CognitoIdentityProviderClient $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }


    public function addCustomAttributes(string $userPoolName, string $attributes)
    {
        $userPool = $this->getResource($userPoolName);

        return $this->client->addCustomAttributes([
            'UserPoolId' => $userPool['PhysicalResourceId'],
            'CustomAttributes' => $attributes,
        ]);
    }
```

How do I set the account ID or profile / role for addCustomAttributes?

Comment: You mind elaborating what do you mean by "account ID" and "role"? What it has to do with custom attributes?

Comment: @AleksanderWons Thanks for the question. By account ID I mean the AWS account ID (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html) and by role I mean IAM role (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles.html)

Comment: @AleksanderWons but I think I worked out that it's due to a configuration of IAM role, see below

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to ensure the IAM role for that particular action was able to do that to that resource and user pool

e.g.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Action": [
            "cognito-idp:AdminGetUser",
            "cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes",
            "cognito-idp:ChangePassword",
            "cognito-idp:ConfirmForgotPassword",
            "cognito-idp:DeleteUser",
            "cognito-idp:GetUser",
            "cognito-idp:ListUsers",
            "cognito-idp:SignUp",
            "cognito-idp:UpdateUserAttributes"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:123456789:userpool/eu-west-1_abcdef",
            "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:123456789:userpool/eu-west-1_ghijk",
            "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:123456789:userpool/eu-west-1_lmnop"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
]
```

}